# How to fix an issue where users aren't moving AD groups

Tags: powershell

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$users = Get-Content -Path .\userlist.txt
$group = "Nitro_Win7"
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($user in $users){
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Win7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Win10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose

If ($members -contains $user) {
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Nitro_Win7" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose 
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Nitro_Win10" -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}
}
```

The list of users are migrating successfully from the "Win7" group to the "Win10" group. However, the second step in the if statement does not seem to be working properly. The goal is to also have users removed from "Nitro_Win7" and added to "Nitro_Win10" if they are a member of "Nitro_Win7". After running, if users are a member of "Nitro_Win7", they stay in "Nitro_Win7". This is not working as hoped. Please help!

Comment: What exactly is in the `userlist.txt` file? User SamAccountNames?.  Both the `Add-ADGroupMember` and `Remove-ADGroupMember` need either the DistinguishedName, GUID, SID or SamAccountName for the `-Members` property.  Therefore, you need to do `$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName` instead of the `Name` property.

Comment: Userlist.txt contains usernames like this: jsmith

Comment: Change `If ($members -contains $user)` to `If ($members.SamAccountName -contains $user)`

Comment: ditto to @AdminOfThings, but then remove the `Select -ExpandProperty Name` alltogether, otherwise `$members` will be just a string array of user names and you need the SamAccountName property.

Comment: Please don't ask a new question (or add new requirements to this question) in a comment. Instead, post a new question, add all requirements and the code you have tried in there. Quite possible that with the answers given in the comments on this question you can figure it out yourself?